# Resque workers failing in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I have a model which contains the following:

```
  def fetch_austlii
    Resque.enqueue(FetchAustliiJob, self.id) # Queue the job for later.
  end
```

This dispatches the app/workers/fetch_austlii_job.rb file:

```
class FetchAustliiJob

  @queue = :fetch_queue

  def self.perform(profile_id)
    @profile = Profile.find(profile_id)
    AustliiResource.fetch(@profile.name).each do |resource|
      @profile.austlii_resources.create!(resource.attributes) if @profile.austlii_resources.find_all_by_url(resource.url).empty?
    end
  end

end
```

In development (OS X, Ruby 1.9.2, Rails3, Postgres, Redis-server, Foreman) it works fine.  The job retrieves information from the internet just like it should.  However, in production (Ubuntu, Ruby 1.9.2, Passenger) it fails with:

```
Class
FetchAustliiJob
Arguments
2
Exception
NoMethodError
Error
undefined method `austlii_resources' for #<Profile:0x00000002fab6b0>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're running the workers in the correct environment (production vs development) on the server.

If you haven't already tried, you may want to create a `config/setup_load_paths.rb` to load the RVM environment (source: [RVM Passenger docs](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/passenger/)):

```
if ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'] && ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'].include?('rvm')
  begin
    rvm_path     = File.dirname(File.dirname(ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME']))
    rvm_lib_path = File.join(rvm_path, 'lib')
    $LOAD_PATH.unshift rvm_lib_path
    require 'rvm'
    RVM.use_from_path! File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__))
  rescue LoadError
    # RVM is unavailable at this point.
    raise "RVM ruby lib is currently unavailable."
  end
end

ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = File.expand_path('../Gemfile', File.dirname(__FILE__))
require 'bundler/setup'
```

Comment: The production server has the environment variable RAILS_ENV set to "production".  I have tried switching this to "development", but it errors in the same fashion.  I am suspecting Passenger is not picking up the project specific RVM gems, although I cannot be sure.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a potential solution to the Passenger/RVM problem.